# Debugging react native navigation auth callback

Tags: react-native, navigation, expo, auth0, react-native-navigation

I've got a react native expo with expo router 2 (react-navigation/native 6) app, and I'm using `react-native-auth0` for auth. I get a successful login (confirmed by the auth0 console), but upon auth success callback, my app console prints out a warning saying:

```
The navigation state parsed from the URL contains routes not present in the root navigator.
This usually means that the linking configuration doesn't match the navigation structure.
See https://reactnavigation.org/docs/configuring-links for more details on how to specify
a linking configuration.
```

and the screen stays on my login page.

How can I debug this and understand what callback was attempted and at which route?
Is maybe my android package name or scheme wrong?